# Why is it still not possible to shut-down the PC when LibreOffice-quickstart is active?

Tags: libreoffice

The bug already exists for a long time (also with OpenOffice), but it seems like nobody can fix it.

Why is it not possible to shut-down the PC when LibreOffice-quickstart is active?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org/+bug/562027) that includes a workaround:

- Run `gksu gedit /usr/lib/libreoffice/basis3.3/share/registry/main.xcd`
- Search for the key *DocumentStoreUIEnabled* in the first line and change it to *false*.

Have you tried that?

Comment: but why do we have to run these commands? it should work without....

Comment: It should, it doesn't - that's why it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As the version of this day (3.5.4), it's possible to have quick-launch enabled. It still shows a message when you turn off (or suspend or anything else) the machine though.